# How to find the time of request for a page at server

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am writing a code to find the time when any page is requested by the browser.
And when the response send by the server.
I have looped through Request collection using following

```
    foreach (string s in Request.Params.Keys)
    {
       Response.Write(s + ":" + Request.Params[s]);
    }
```

But I am not getting any variable for this purpose. 
Is there any other way.

Comment: The code in your question seems to run on the server. Therefore, the time the page was requested should be very close to `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: do not read it from params sent from client side, instead use `Application_BeginRequest` event from Global.asax

Comment: Yest this code will run on server. But there may be some cases where the user's internal proxy or the network connecting to the server is slow or the user is using the low band with.

Answer (score 1):

you should use the httpModule events - pipline methods   - ehich can be accessed via global.asax file.:

<kbd>Application_BeginRequest</kbd>

Occurs as the first event in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution when ASP.NET responds to a request.

<kbd>Application_EndRequest</kbd>

Occurs as the last event in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution when ASP.NET responds to a request.

there , you can check `DateTime.Now.`

### edit

if you want to know when the person requested the page ( via link or something - not the GO button) -

you can set a hiddenField which will have the getDate() in JS.

this element will be sent to the server as a part of form inputs.

Comment: I think on Application_BeginRequest I will get the time when begin request will come in focous. I wanted to know at what time user has requested the page. Or what time used click the go button of the browser.

Comment: @Royi, even if `new Date().toUTCString()` is used, nothing prevents the client machine from being configured with an arbitrary date. As always, the client should not be trusted by server-side code.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi you right but its the max he can do.. if he want to trust client - so my way ( second one) if he doesnt - so only in the beginning of the http module events....

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi one soluton is to get by ajax  - when document.ready - the time from server and then to "client increment" the time. .... nice no ? ( the seed time is from server  , later its the js).

Comment: @Royi, no need to use AJAX then, just have the server render the current time as the value of the hidden field you mentioned, and have the client update the field before submitting :) That said, it does not look like a very robust solution anyway (a malicious user could change the client's time after the page has loaded, and I'm not sure the effect that disabling and re-enabling Javascript would have on calls to `setTimeout()`/`setInterval()`...

Comment: If I can get the IP-Address of the client then why can I not get the time of request. Is there not any way of getting the time of the user pressing the go button. I can use hidden field on my form and on the next request I can get the value. But what about the first request??

Comment: @krshekhar ip address is in the request header. time isnt.

Comment: @Royi and the header doesn't contain request time is it so?

Comment: @krshekhar no. take a look at request to stackoverflow.com `GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.24 Safari/536.5
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: windows-1255,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: __qca=P0-1042589948-1336666535601; usr=t=GCOuPb2R8Uuw&s=6jFRjqsQEqzW; (organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=
If-Modified-Since: Fri, 11 May 2012 05:42:51 GMT`